# Mixpanel: event color in activity feed

Tags: mixpanel

I have the following events in mixpanel:

[image: screenshot]

I'm aware the orange one is because it is a Ruby triggered event, but the blue and the teal are triggered through JS.

What does the color mean? I could not find any caption on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is actually randomly determined, it is not at all dependent upon the event or its' properties. If you were to examine a different user's activity feed, there's a good chance you'd find the "Login" event under a different color.